# ggplot geom_point plot two categorical variables and fill in missing

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi suppose I have the following dataframe and want to generate the plot below.  I can plot this simply, however, for the missing value: s2,b1 is there a way I can add a circle with a different color? basically I want to fill in a grey point for anywhere in the plot that does not have a black.  If there say 5 samples this can get complicated fast.

```
temp = data.frame ( sample=c("s1","s1","s2"), drug=c("a","b","a"))
ggplot(data=temp, aes(x=sample, y= factor ( drug) ) )+ 
    geom_point(size=20)
```

[image]

Comment: If you just want another point at an arbitrary position, you can add it as a new layer: `+ geom_point(x=2, y=2, color = 'red’)`. But is that really what you want? Is that point in your data somewhere? Or in another dataset?

Comment: @divibisan basically I want to fill in a grey point for anywhere in the plot that does not have a black. So if this was a bigger dataframe I want it to automatically do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try `table`

```
ggplot(data=as.data.frame(table(temp)), aes(x=sample, y= factor ( drug) ) )+ 
  geom_point(aes(color=as.factor(Freq)), size = 20) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("grey70", "black"))
```

[image]